# CPanel API - Creating Subdomains

Tags: cpanel

I'm writing a script so I can create subdomains on my account.  I'm following this example:

[CPanel API Example](http://kb.site5.com/control/cpanel/cpanelwhm-api/)

My question:  How can I create subdomains?  The docs on Cpanel's API don't show this very well.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using version 2 of the API. Below is a direct link to the instructions to create subdomains.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/cPanel+API+2+Functions+-+SubDomain%3A%3Aaddsubdomain